# Cmder no funciona bien con neoVim(Sintaxis)

Tags: consola, vim, nvim, cmder

mi problema esta relacionado con neovim, estaba utilizando la terminal cmder, el punto es que cuando inicio neovim, no aparecen ajustes graficos, como en este caso la sintaxis resaltada

[image: Como aparece(encmder)]

[image: Como deberia aparecer]

Answer (score 0):

Abra la configuración de Cmder y vaya a `Startup -> Environment`, agregue la siguiente configuración: `set TERM=xterm-256color`